# How to setup vim to have the same tab and space conventions as the opened file has?

Tags: vim

Is it possible to use vim with a buffer based {expandtab, tabstop, shiftwidth} setup?
For example I edit a file which uses 2 spaces to indent

```
stuct A {
  void foo () {
    int x;
  }
};
```

And an other file with tabs

```
int main() {
    int i; // \t is used as indentation
    return i;
}
```

Of course I could setup the values manually buffer by buffer, but I want vim to do this automatically. Can this be done? Or is there a plugin which does this for me?

Comment: Note that I need a solution which can be used even if the file or the project does not support vim specific directives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [vim-sleuth](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sleuth) to automatically detect the tab convention in the file you are opening.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the mentioned *vim-sleuth* is my [IndentConsistencyCop plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1690), combined with [IndentConsistencyCopAutoCmds plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1691). (The plugin page has links to even more alternative plugins.)

Answer (score 1):

You can embed vim commands in a file. Example:

```
/* vim: set noai ts=4 sw=4: */
```

When you open that file, those commands will be executed. You can see more on the topic at http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Modeline_magic.

Comment: I think a project's files should be editor agnostic. E.g. I wouldn't be happy if in my project's repository somebody would add eclipse project files just because she uses that editor. I think the same is true for vim as well. This is especially true for open source projects, where there are lot of people and they use a variety of editors/tools.

Comment: @GaborMarton, good point. For such files, embedding vim commands is potentially detrimental.

Answer (score 0):

### Use Modelines

You have just described the use case for [modelines](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#modeline). Rather than trying to guess the proper indentation levels, you *tell* Vim what the proper indentation levels are for the file. A team would commit that as part of the source, and then everyone who opens up the file in Vim would share the same settings.

For example, you might set tab expansion on, and both tab-stops and shift width to two with:

```
/* vim: set et ts=2 sw=2: */
```